# Php problem checking file upload value

Tags: php, file-upload

Ok this might be a simple problem but I cannot figure this out at all.... I am trying to check if the user is trying to upload a file, upload it else execute some other code, but:

```
if(isset($_FILES['rv_img']['name']) && !empty($_FILES['rv_img']))
        {
            echo "here ";print_r($_FILES);
                }
else
                {
                        echo "no file uploaded";
                }
```

I want to see "no file uploaded" cause I am submitting the form with blank file input field.. but instead I am getting:

```
here Array ( [rv_img] => Array ( [name] => [type] => [tmp_name] => [error] => 4 [size] => 0 ) [thumb_img] => Array ( [name] => [type] => [tmp_name] => [error] => 4 [size] => 0 ) )
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
if ( isset($_FILES["file"]) && $_FILES["file"]["error"]==0 )
{
  $file_name= $_FILES["file"]["name"];
  move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], YOUR PATH TO STORE FILE. $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
}
else
echo("No file uploaded");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($_FILES['rv_img']['name']) && !empty($_FILES['rv_img']['name']))
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because `!empty($_FILES['rv_img'])` will always return true. Try with `!empty($_FILES['rv_img']['name'])`.

Answer (score 0):

You get the error code 4, which is UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE constant.
All the file upload error constants can be seen at http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php.
Try checking this condition:

```
if (... && $_FILES['rv_img']['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) { ...
```